# https URL - Ignore cert warning and continue

Tags: python-3.x

How do ignore the warning you continue to get the content of the requested page? I am using the below in Python 3.5.1.

```
import urllib3   
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
urllib3.disable_warnings()
s = requests.get('https://hostname.com/a.txt', verify=False)
print(s)
```

Above is saved as HeartbeatCheck.py and upon running from the command prompt, I am getting the below :-

[image]

> C:\python35\lib\site-packages\requests-2.9.1-py3.5.egg\requests\packages\urllib3
>   \connectionpool.py:791: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS
>   request is bein g made. Adding certificate verification is strongly
>   advised. See: https://urllib
>   3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html   InsecureRequestWarning)

**Complete Resolved code [after J.F. Sebastian's answer]**

```
import requests
import urllib3

from requests.packages import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

from urllib.request import urlopen
s = requests.get('https://txpingappdev01.sddev.lpl.com/pf/heartbeat.ping', verify=False)
print(s.text)
```

Comment: Have you tried click the link named "Disabling Warnings", on the page you get to if you visit the URL in the error message?

Comment: For that matter, why not just enable certificate verification, as described on that page in great detail?

Comment: @KoebmandSTO From the browser, If I manually ignore the warning, I see the contents. No issues in the URL itself.

Comment: @AshishGupta: We're talking about [this page](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance- a newbie in python. Is urllib3 in requests library? How supressing warning from urllib3 will affect call made through requests library?

Comment: From the first line of your code ... import urllib3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `.disable_warnings()` then you should import module that is used by `requests`:

```
from requests.packages import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

There are other ways to [disable warnings](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#disabling-warnings). If possible; you should enable certificate verification instead.

Comment: That was it. I also updated the question to include the complete code.